# Calculations using Columns for Default constraints - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to have a column default to a calculation of other columns? SSMS is giving me an error (SQL Server 2012) that column names can't be used in the context of setting Default constraints for a column.  If this is simply not allowed, is there an explanation based on expression/clause execution (or something else) that explains why this isn't allowed?  Is this specific to SQL Server, or does it apply to other DBMSes?

For this question, let's assume that it makes sense to store the calculated value in the table and not just calculated ad hoc.  I realize that is consideration in DB design.

The obvious workaround is to include the calculation in the INSERT clause, but this separates the information about the column.  It seems to me that would be a more efficient gathering of relevant qualities of the table to keep it in the table.

~Bruce

Answer (score 0):

here you go!

```
declare @flower_order table(
[flower]     [sysname]
, [quantity] [int]
, [price]    [money]
, [tax]      [float]
, [total_price] as round([quantity] * [price] * ( 1 + [tax] )
         , 2));
insert into @flower_order
        ([flower],[quantity],[price],[tax])
values      (N'rose',5,8.25,.08),
        (N'tulip',3,4.74,.0725);
select [flower]
   , [quantity]
   , [price]
   , [tax]
   , [total_price]
from   @flower_order;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Katherine.  I executed this, and I see how this works, not by creating a Default/Binding constraint but by doing an in-place calculation as a parameter of the declare statement.  This wasn't quite what I was reaching for because even if I use the final SELECT clause for an INSERT to my destination table, the table itself still does not have the destination constraint itself.  Other methods of INSERT would not necessarily keep this constraint intact.

Thanks for the idea, though. :)